# PHP explode() built-in function not working as I expected

Tags: php

I tried PHP explod() built-in function to explod my text data stored in a mysql database.
here is I tried sample PHP code:

```
// Get mysql database data(with \n).
$str_in = 
'one
two
three

fore
five

six
';

// Convert \n into <br>.
$str = nl2br($str_in);

// Explode $str and wrapped into <p> tags.
$str_exploded = explode("<br><br>",$str);

foreach($str_exploded as $sub_str) {

    echo '<p>'.$sub_str.'</p>';

}
```

Then I got this output.

```
<p>one<br>
two<br>
three<br>
<br>
fore<br>
five<br>
<br>
six<br>
</p>
```

but this is not what I'm expected. I want somthing like this.

```
<p>one<br>
two<br>
three</p>

<p>fore<br>
five</p>

<p>six</p>
```

how can I achive this? thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `nl2br`? Use can use directly `explode("\n",$str);
`

Comment: Why aren't you just exploding on newlines instead of injecting HTML breaks?

Comment: `<br>` is not string in your case. so php cannot read them.

Answer (score 0):

You incorrectly presume, that `nl2br` function replaces "\n" with `<br>`. In reality it inserts `<br />` before the `\n`. So, `\n\n` becomes `<br />\n<br />\n`. Your

```
explode("<br><br>",$str)
```

doesn't work as expected.

To fix it I used exploding by `\n\n`:

### Code

```
<?php
$str_in =
'one
two
three

fore
five

six
';

$str_exploded = preg_split("/(:?\r?\n){2}/",$str_in);

$n = count($str_exploded);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
    // Convert \n into <br>.
    $str_exploded[$i] = nl2br($str_exploded[$i]);
    echo '<p>'.$str_exploded[$i]."</p>";
    if ($i !== $n - 1)
    {
        print "\n\n";
    }
}
```

### Output

```
<p>one<br />
two<br />
three</p>

<p>fore<br />
five</p>

<p>six<br />
</p>
```

Comment: I think it will break, You can not presume its always `\n\n` like `$str_exploded = explode("\n\n",$str_in);`.

Comment: @rajeshujade: are you talking about `\r`?

Comment: @ Karoly Horvath Yes. Probably its can be more than 2 new line.Its depend on user

Comment: @rajeshujade I updated the answer, for the case of possible \r before \n. I used regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is remove a 
 when its the only thing on the line.

Strreplace should work with the argument "\n
" and a replacement of "\n"